# Не инкрементируется значение i

Tags: javascript

Возник вопрос в коде, а именно не инкрементируется значение this._i.

```js
function Ticker() {
  this._i = 0;
};

Ticker.prototype = {
  tick: function() {
    console.log(this._i, this._i++);
  }
};

var ticker = new Ticker();

setInterval(ticker.tick, 1000);
```

Прошу помощи, заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дело вот в чем. Когда Вы передаете ссылку на функцию `ticker.tick` первым параметром в `setInterval`, контекст (объект `ticker`) туда не попадает. Эта функция вызывается в контексте `window`, у которого свойства `_i` нет. Обратите внимание, я добавил `this._i` в `console.log`, и самое первое обращение к этому свойству, до каких-либо арифметических действий с ним, выводит `undefined`. Надо передавать в `setInterval` обертку функции с контекстом:

```js
function Ticker() {
  this._i = 0;
};

Ticker.prototype = {
  tick: function() {
    console.log(this._i, this._i++);
  }
};

var ticker = new Ticker();

setInterval(ticker.tick.bind(ticker), 1000);
// или setInterval(Ticker.prototype.tick.bind(ticker), 1000);
```

Answer (score 4):

> Возник вопрос в коде, а именно не инкрементируется значение this._i.

Происходит потеря контекста при вызове `setInterval`

### Вариант №1:

```js
function Ticker() {
  this._i = 0;
};
Ticker.prototype = {
  tick: function() {
    console.log(this._i++);
  }
};
var ticker = new Ticker();
// Вызов функции, обертка сохранит контекст 
setInterval(() => {
  ticker.tick()
}, 1000);
```

---

### Вариант №2:

```js
function Ticker() {
  this._i = 0;
  // Убрали в саму функцию
  this.tick = () => {
    console.log(this._i++);
  }
};
var ticker = new Ticker();
setInterval(
  ticker.tick // Сохранит контекст
, 1000);
```

---

- [Методы объектов и контекст вызова](https://learn.javascript.ru/objects-more)

Comment: Хорошо. Скажите, почему изначальный вариант при каждом тике выводит NaN? В чем именно недоработка алгоритма?